# Web application unable to find database

Tags: asp.net, ms-access, web-applications, connection-string

In my web application, I am using Microsoft Access as database.
I have put my database under App_Data folder and used following code as connection string.

```
private string source;
string connString;

source = HostingEnvironment.MapPath(@"/App_Data/SecretDatabase.accdb");

connString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + source + ";Persist Security Info=False;";
```

Its works perfectly when I debug application in local machine.
But when I publish it to web server, web application is unable to connect to the database.

Anybody know the reason behind it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with

```
 source = HostingEnvironment.MapPath(@"~/App_Data/SecretDatabase.accdb");
```

The tilde character "~" represents the root of the application